# Need help for procedures in Python 3.6/3.2

Tags: python, stored-procedures

Me and my friends are working on a project at school and we need help with some procedures. We know how to create and call one in, but for some reason it isn't working with our current code.

Whenever we try to use the procedure with certain parts of the code, this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\board game edited.py", line 78, in <module>
    P1()
  File "F:\board game edited.py", line 53, in P1
    counter1 = counter1 + dicetotal
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter1' referenced before assignment
```

Here is the code:

```
import random

counter1 = 0
counter2 = 0

print("***********************************BOARD GAME**********************************")
print(" ")
print("***********************************GAME RULES**********************************")
print(" ")
print("----------------------------Game is for 2 players only-------------------------")
print(" ")
print(">The game board is a 7x7 board going up to 49")
print(" ")
print("43 44 45 46 47 48 49")
print("42 41 40 39 38 37 36")
print("29 30 31 32 33 34 35")
print("28 27 26 25 24 23 22")
print("15 16 17 18 19 20 21")
print("14 13 12 11 10 9  8 ")
print("1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ")
print(" ")
print(">The objective is to be the first player to reach space 49")
print(" ")
print(">There are 2 die, if you roll the same number twice, you will go back 
the number of spaces you rolled")
print(" ")
print(">If you land on spaces 27, 31 and 47, you will go back to space 24")
print(" ")
print(">Press ENTER to play")
input()

print("**********************************START 
GAME***********************************")
input()

print("Starting positions for both players = 0")
print(" ")

with open("Game Messages.txt","r") as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    my_list = data.splitlines()

def P1():
    print(my_list[0])
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    print("dice 1 =",dice1)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print("dice 2 =",dice2)
    dicetotal = dice1 + dice2
    print("dice total =",dicetotal)
    if dice1 == dice2:
        counter1 = counter1 - dicetotal
        print(my_list[1])
    else:
        counter1 = counter1 + dicetotal
    if counter1 >= 49:
        print("P1 space = 49")
    if counter1 <= 0:
        print("P1 space = 0")
    if counter1 <=49:
        print("P1 space =",counter1)
    if counter1 == 47:
        counter1 = 24
        print(my_list[2])
    if counter1 == 27:
        counter1 = 24
        print(my_list[3])
    if counter1 == 31:
        counter1 = 24
        print(my_list[4])
    if counter1 >= 49:
        print(" ")
        print(my_list[5])
        print(" ")
        print("Press ENTER to exit the game")
        input()
        exit()
    input()

def P2():
    print(my_list[6])
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    print("dice 1 =",dice1)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print("dice 2 =",dice2)
    dicetotal = dice1 + dice2
    print("dice total =",dicetotal)
    if dice1 == dice2:
        counter2 = counter2 - dicetotal
        print(my_list[7])
    else:
        counter2 = counter2 + dicetotal
    if counter2 >= 49:
        print("P2 space = 49")
    if counter1 <= 0:
        print("P2 space = 0")
    if counter1 <= 49:
        print("P2 space =",counter2)
    if counter2 == 47:
        counter2 = 24
        print(my_list[8])
    if counter2 == 27:
        counter2 = 24
        print(my_list[9])
    if counter2 == 31:
        counter2 = 24
        print(my_list[10])
    if counter2 >= 49:
        print(" ")
        print(my_list[11])
        print(" ")
        print("Press ENTER to exit the game")
        input()
        exit()
    input()

P1()
P2()
```

We would be extremely grateful if you helped us in any way, thank you!

Comment: In your if/else statement you have `counter1 = counter1-dicetotal`. what is the value of the counter1 on the right side of the equation when you debug it?

Comment: It would be counter1's previous value. Eg, if the previous value was 14 and the die were both 4, the new value would be 6. The starting value for counter 1 is 0, but it's assigned in an earlier part of the code.

Comment: Based on your comments on other answers, you should show where you are actually assigning counter1. We can't know for certain that you did (little mistakes happen all the time). The code you provided indicates that you didn't and we can't assume what you didn't show us. Please read more in [mcve].

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.
Also, *please* edit your posting to a **MCVE**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local variable `counter1` has not been defined in that function. You have to either assign it a value within the function, make it a global variable, or pass it in.

Comment: I assigned it in an earlier part of the code which isn't shown, before the procedure. Would I have to assign it inside?

Comment: Yes, either by declaring it above the function (not just in code that is executed first) or by passing it into the function (change the function to `P1(counter1)`

Answer (score 1):

The message tells you what happened.

```
if dice1 == dice2:
    counter1 = counter1 - dicetotal
    print(my_list[1])
else:
    counter1 = counter1 + dicetotal
```

When you start this code, `counter1` does not have an assigned value.  You're trying to add the dice roll to a quantity that doesn't exist.  You have to give `counter1` an initial value before you get here.

If you want to utilize *and update* an external variable with that name, you need the line

```
global counter1
```

at the top of your function.

For SO purposes, ed need you to supply *all* of the code that affects the problem.  Telling us that there's a critical line that you didn't post is a bait-and-switch -- no fair!  :-)

Comment: This is just a part of the code, earlier I did assign counter1's value. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You posted the entire function?  I can see all the way to the top of that scope, and you have *not* initialized `counter1`.  As you've used that variable, it's a local value.  Anything you initialized outside of the function is an unrelated variable.

Comment: I used the global counter1 line and it worked! Thank you so much!!